# IPv6 Address Python

Tags: python, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

I have a IPv6 address equal to "2001:200:e000::/35".
However, I can't input it on function ip_address() from library ipaddress.
The function works perfectly for addresses that don't contain "/", such as IPv4 "1.0.0.0" and IPv6 "2001:12f8:0:17::23":

```
ipaddress.ip_address(unicode("1.0.0.0","utf-8"))
```

returns:

```
IPv4Address(u'1.0.0.0')
```

And

```
ipaddress.ip_address(unicode("2001:12f8:0:17::23","utf-8"))
```

returns:

```
IPv6Address(u'2001:12f8:0:17::23')
```

However, when I try it for IPv6 "2001:200:e000::/35",

```
ipaddress.ip_address(unicode("2001:200:e000::/35","utf-8"))
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipaddress.py", line 168, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: u'2001:200:e000::/35' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

How am I supposed to input the IP address that contains "/" to ip_address?

Comment: I guess you already know that the one you are trying does not fit to be a IPv6 address, still you want to put it?

Comment: the slash denotes that its not a single address, for ip6 /32 actually represents a range of 65536 addresses. so it is not an address in itself.

Answer (score 3):

"IP addresses with / in them" as you call them are not actually IP addresses. They are IP networks (which means a range of IP addresses) in something called "CIDR Notation".

You can process IP networks using `ipaddress.ip_network()`. For example:

```
>>> ipn = ipaddress.ip_network("2001:200:e000::/35")
>>> ipn.num_addresses
9903520314283042199192993792
```

Comment: It is worth noting that "IP address/prefix length" is quite common to indicate address and subnet size. Unlike IPv4, where an "all zero" host part designates the network address, in IPv6 `2001:db8::/64` (all zeroes in the last 64 bits) is a valid host address and prefix. But a prefix size of `/35`, as in the question, would not be a single subnet.